# ASP.NET MVC - Partial View Design Pattern?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns

We have a project where we have created 2 separate areas to be used by administrators of a site, depending on which Role the authenticated user belongs to.  There exists some overlapping functionality between the two areas, but not enough that we would combine them into a single area.  So what we have done for the UI is create some partial views that are included from similar views within the two areas, however I'm having trouble deciding where to physically place the partial view.

It doesn't make sense to place it in ~/Views/Shared, as none of the root-level views use this particular partial view.  It also doesn't make sense to place the file in ~/Areas/[Area]/Views/Shared, as neither of the areas directly "owns" this partial view.

What would you consider a best-practice location in this scenario?

Comment: If you don't put the partials in the Shared folder, I don't think you'll be able to use the built in html helpers to call them.

Comment: You can access any partial view from within any view.  It will look in the current, then shared folder(s) by default, but you can also specify a location via Html.Partial("~/Areas/[Area]/Views/Shared/MyPartial.cshtml", model)

Answer (score 2):

I think ~/Views/Shared is not the best solution for you here, although those partial views are really **shared** between two *Areas*, which are separate controllers, as I assume.

However, you can use

```
Html.Partial(pathToView, model)
```

function to include the partial view, which may be put wherever you want.
Even the example you've mentioned:

```
Html.Partial("~/Areas/[Area]/Views/Shared/PartialViewFile.cshtml", model)
```

Or:

```
Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/PartialViewFile.cshtml", model)
```

This solution seems more relevant for me, as all Areas share views, and they do not belong to the particular area.